# Can't install or uninstall oracle-database-ee-19c on my Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, oracle, database

So I tried to install Oracle 19c database on my Ubuntu 20.04 (as in my pc, not a virtual machine or anything, my OS is Ubuntu itself)

I downloaded the .rpm file instead of the zip (there was no deb file for it) which was by mistake really I used alien for converting the .rpm file to .deb which took really long, like at least 10-15 minutes also lot's of warning were there Especially this one multiple lines

warning: ras.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY

After the whole thing was over I installed it

It took some more time as well And it showed some warnings as well

The installation was complete

After that and after looking for ways to set it up I tried to run this "runInstaller" which starts the GUI installation But it doesn't go any further than the first step Just shows the error

[INS-32042] The Installer has detected that the user (oracle) is not member of the central inventory group: oracle

There's a uninstaller file too but it says it won't run as root and when I run from home directory it says it won't run coz it needs to be run from the "Oracle home user" which installed it

Please help how to install or uninstall or remove it I'm fed up of this

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu does not support Oracle 19C. Therefore we have to install it on DOCKER.

**Installing docker to Ubuntu**

Update software repositories

```
• sudo apt-get update
```

Uninstall older docker versions

```
• sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io
```

Install docker

```
• sudo apt install docker.io
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4i24.png)

Give ‘y’ as yes to continue.

Start and Automate docker

```
• sudo systemctl start docker

• sudo systemctl enable docker
```

Oracle 19C should download into the docker. We are going to pull(download) Oracle 19C image from docker hub.

To check pulled and imported images to docker.

```
• sudo docker images
```

(Still there are no images)

Pull oracle 19c image

```
• docker pull banglamon/oracle193db:19.3.0-ee
```

After pull completed, check images

[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYS6G.png)

It’s good to save to backup the docker image.

```
• docker save banglamon/oracle193db | gzip > oracle19c.tar.gz
```

banglamon/oracle193db -Repository******oracle19c.tar.gz-save as name

This will take a few minutes to backup.

[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dkw8.png)

You can find the exported file in /home

**Installing Oracle 19C on docker**

It will be easier if you have docker image info on sight(root user)

```
• docker images
```

Below command is to run the image.

```
• docker run -d --name oracle19db -p 1521:1521 -e ORACLE_SID=SE -e ORACLE_PDB=SEPDB -e ORACLE_PWD=Oracle123 -v /u01/app/oracle/oradata:/opt/oracle/oradata banglamon/oracle193db:19.3.0-ee
```

banglamon/oracle193db-Repository******19.3.0-ee-Image Tag

[8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYn5S.png)

After pressing ENTER you can see the container ID.

Installation runs in the background. We can check the status of the process in another terminal by below commands.

```
• docker ps -a


• docker logs -f [container ID]
```

[9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9k4y.png)

This will take time as per your system configuration.
Once the process finished, you can see DATABASE IS READY TO USE and the last line should be XDB INITIALIZED and no further logs will be generated.

[10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S01gM.png)

Ctrl+C to exit the log.

When we run the image, it will create a container in docker. To check container

```
• docker ps -a
```

We have to start the container in order to work.

```
• docker start [container ID] or [container NAME]
```

Now execute the container.

```
• docker exec -it oracle19db bash -c “source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog”
```

After opening Oracle, test the localhost connection

```
• conn / as sysdba
```

If it’s connected, all good.....!

You have to make Oracle up and running every time you restart your PC.
Use the below steps;

Log into terminal as root

```
• sudo su
```

Check docker processes

```
• docker ps -a
```

[12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF6vg.png)

Start the oracle container

```
• docker start [container ID]
```

Execute the container

```
• docker exec -it oracle19db bash -c “source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog”
```

[14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeHw8.png)

Now you're good to go..

Comment: Reference :
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04
https://hub.docker.com/r/banglamon/oracle193db
https://mkc110891.medium.com/oracle-19c-on-ubuntu-18-04-docker-6898cd2916f9
https://serverfault.com/questions/923623/persist-alter-session-set-oracle-script-true-in-oracle-12c